# How many non-isomorphic binary trees can you make with 3 vertices?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, trees

I know that by drawing it out there is only 1 non-isomorphic tree with 3 vertices, which I got correctly. However, I presume that there is also 1 non-isomorphic **binary** tree. This is where I am wrong. Why is the answer not 1?

Comment: Any binary tree with three vertices is necessarily also a tree with three vertices, so there is clearly at most one. There is clearly also at least one, writing down the obvious one. Thus, youa re not wrong.

Comment: I think I know what you mean, but there is no such thing as a “non-isomorphic tree.” Maybe you should say “one binary tree with three vertices, up to isomorphism.”

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Binary trees are usually rooted. If isomorphisms are required to map roots to roots, there are two distinct rooted trees with three vertices (both are binary).

Binary trees may also be ordered: each node may have a left child, a right child, both, or neither. Depending on your definition of isomorphism, isomorphisms might be restricted to map left children to left children and right children to right children. In this case there are five distinct binary trees.

Comment: OK. I'll buy it. Sorry about my confusion! +1